# html как задать стили option в select?

Tags: html, css, select

Есть select, и мне необходимо задать стили его option. Как это сделать? Что ба на mac тоже работало, как пример что бы option были с background black?

Comment: Никак, внешний вид option почти не контролируется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартным Select-Option никак. Делаешь HTML разметку, один div стилизуешь под внешний вид закрытого select, второй div - раскрытого. Внутри второго div создаешь подпункты (тоже div, или ul li на твой выбор), стилизуешь их как душе угодно. Далее при помощи JavaScript пишешь функцию, которая при клике на div имитирующий закрытый select показывает div с элементами, а при повторном клике на него же - скрывает. А для клика на любой элемент тоже пишешь функцию, которая скрывает div с элементами, и меняет текст внутри div имитирующего закрытый select на текст выбранного элемента.

НО. Тут стоит учесть и то, что у некоторых людей может быть отключен JS в браузере, и тогда эта конструкция перестанет работать. Поэтому обязательно нужно на его месте в тегах

```
<noscript> </noscript>
```

Разместить обычный select.

Это только кажется сложным и страшным. Руководство к действию есть, вперед и с песней! Гораздо лучше поймешь и лучше усвоится, когда сам разберешься и сделаешь, чем если скопируешь и вставишь готовый код. Желаю удачи!

Comment: Спасибо большое, думаю поможет.